# How show number 2000000 as 2,000,000 in Extjs number field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm developing an app with extjs-6. I have a `numberfield` as follow:

```
{
      xtype: 'numberfield',
      name: 'rent',
      minWidth: 150,
      allowBlank: true,
    keyNavEnabled: true,
    mouseWheelEnabled: true,
    hideTrigger: true,
}
```

The number that users must enter is a big number like `20000000`. I want to this number show like `20,000,000`. **How can I do it**?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built in Ext Format method.

```
{
    xtype : 'textfield',
    listeners : {
        blur : function(t) {
            var val = t.getValue();
            val = val.replace(/,/g, '');
            t.setValue(Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000'));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Or override the method valueToRaw and return formatted value Ext.util.Format.number(val, '0,000')

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener. When value is changed you format it.

[Ext.field.Number-event-change](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-modern/#!/api/Ext.field.Number-event-change)

Now to format it:

```
newValue = "12345678";
newValue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
// 12,345,678
```

Comment: There is no need to do self developed stuff, ExtJs has already util methods and valueToRaw method to achieve this.